# How to groupby a date range and a column then plot a bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

Let's say, I have this specific dataframe below.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

periods = 46670
dates = pd.date_range(start='2005-07-01', end='2021-06-01', periods=periods)  
operating_airline = ['Lufthansa','Air Canada','American Air','American Pan Pacific','Emirates','KLM','Scandinavian Air',
                    'Singapore Airlines','Japan Air','Air Force 1']  
geo_summary = ['Domestic', 'International']  
geo_region = ['US','Canada','South America', 'Europe','Nothern Europe']

np.random.seed(2002)  # for repeatable values
operating_airline = np.random.choice(operating_airline, size=periods)  
geo_summary = np.random.choice(geo_summary, size=periods)  
geo_region = np.random.choice(geo_region, size=periods)  
passenger_count = np.random.randint(1000,10000, size=periods)  
    
test = pd.DataFrame({'Dates':dates,'Operating_Airlines':operating_airline,'Geo_Summary':geo_summary,'Geo_Region':geo_region,'Passenger_Count':passenger_count})

# display(test.head())

                          Dates Operating_Airlines    Geo_Summary     Geo_Region  Passenger_Count
0 2005-07-01 00:00:00.000000000         Air Canada       Domestic  South America             9958
1 2005-07-01 02:59:23.667530909       American Air       Domestic         Europe             7853
2 2005-07-01 05:58:47.335061818          Japan Air  International         Canada             3162
3 2005-07-01 08:58:11.002592727        Air Force 1  International  South America             5100
4 2005-07-01 11:57:34.670123636          Japan Air  International         Canada             5382
```

What i've been ***trying to achieve*** mostly;
**Note:** The bars should have annotations(although im aware of how to do this part, id still like see a different approach. if there is).
My issue was that Im unable to customise `Dates` format(e.g. y-m-d) & date range(6month, a year) simultaneously plotting 2 variables **Air Canada** and **American Pan Pacific** in the `Operating_Airline` using only Pandas **&/or** Matplotlib. Im open to all types of answers ofcourse!

How could I customize date ranges further if I decided to plot for a yearly period?

[image]

**What I've tried(failed & unable to find a solution) to;**

```
plt.bar(test['Date'], test['Operating_Airline'].count(), label='Test', width=20, color=['red'])
plt.bar(test['Date'], test['Operating_Airline'].count(), label='Test_1', width=20)
plt.title('Test')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use [`pandas.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) with [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group `'Dates'` by a frequency (e.g. `'6M'`, `'1Y'`)

  - This results in a long dataframe, which can be plotted with [`seaborn.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) or [`seaborn.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html).
- The dates can be reformatted with [`pandas.Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html), **after** using `Grouper`, because `Grouper` requires the dates to be a `datetime Dtype`, but `.dt.strftime` converts the dates to strings.
- Use [`pandas.DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to reshape the dataframe to a wide form, and plot with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html).
- From `matplotlib 3.4.0`, [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html) can be used to easily annotate bars.

  - See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804) for additional details and examples using `.bar_label`.
- Since there are many dates, it's better to plot horizontal bars, than vertical bars (for spacing). For vertical bars with pandas, use `'bar'` instead of `'barh'`, and for seaborn, swap the columns passed to `x=` and `y=`.
- **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.4.3`, `matplotlib 3.5.1`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

```py
# use groupby grouper and specify freq='1Y' or '6M'
dfg = test.groupby([pd.Grouper(key="Dates", freq="1Y"), 'Operating_Airlines']).Operating_Airlines.count().reset_index(name='counts')

# now change the format of the dates
dfg.Dates = dfg.Dates.dt.strftime('%Y-%m')

# pivot dfg so it can be plotted directly with pandas
dfp = dfg.pivot(index='Dates', columns='Operating_Airlines', values='counts')

# plot dfp
ax = dfp.plot(kind='barh', width=0.90, figsize=(10, 22))

# move the legend
ax.legend(title='Operating_Airlines', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5), loc='center left', frameon=False)

# annotate the bars
for c in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(c, label_type='edge', fontsize=8)
```

- Instead of plotting `dfp` (wide form) with pandas, plot `dfg` (long form) directly with seaborn.

```py
import seaborn as sns

# plot dfg
g = sns.catplot(kind='bar', data=dfg, y='Dates', x='counts', hue='Operating_Airlines', height=20, aspect=0.5)

for c in g.ax.containers:
    g.ax.bar_label(c, label_type='edge', fontsize=8)
```

[image]

---

### DataFrame Views

#### `dfg`

```py
       Dates    Operating_Airlines  counts
0    2005-12            Air Canada     139
1    2005-12           Air Force 1     147
2    2005-12          American Air     138
3    2005-12  American Pan Pacific     148
4    2005-12              Emirates     159
5    2005-12             Japan Air     136
6    2005-12                   KLM     137
7    2005-12             Lufthansa     151
8    2005-12      Scandinavian Air     166
9    2005-12    Singapore Airlines     156
10   2006-12            Air Canada     277
11   2006-12           Air Force 1     297
12   2006-12          American Air     299
13   2006-12  American Pan Pacific     286
14   2006-12              Emirates     312
15   2006-12             Japan Air     297
16   2006-12                   KLM     312
17   2006-12             Lufthansa     290
18   2006-12      Scandinavian Air     270
19   2006-12    Singapore Airlines     290
20   2007-12            Air Canada     301
21   2007-12           Air Force 1     268
22   2007-12          American Air     267
23   2007-12  American Pan Pacific     297
24   2007-12              Emirates     298
25   2007-12             Japan Air     291
26   2007-12                   KLM     295
27   2007-12             Lufthansa     290
28   2007-12      Scandinavian Air     316
29   2007-12    Singapore Airlines     307
30   2008-12            Air Canada     296
31   2008-12           Air Force 1     279
32   2008-12          American Air     286
33   2008-12  American Pan Pacific     316
34   2008-12              Emirates     306
35   2008-12             Japan Air     290
36   2008-12                   KLM     286
37   2008-12             Lufthansa     284
38   2008-12      Scandinavian Air     281
39   2008-12    Singapore Airlines     314
40   2009-12            Air Canada     312
41   2009-12           Air Force 1     264
42   2009-12          American Air     329
43   2009-12  American Pan Pacific     276
44   2009-12              Emirates     284
45   2009-12             Japan Air     273
46   2009-12                   KLM     313
47   2009-12             Lufthansa     304
48   2009-12      Scandinavian Air     292
49   2009-12    Singapore Airlines     283
50   2010-12            Air Canada     300
51   2010-12           Air Force 1     279
52   2010-12          American Air     291
53   2010-12  American Pan Pacific     292
54   2010-12              Emirates     284
55   2010-12             Japan Air     309
56   2010-12                   KLM     303
57   2010-12             Lufthansa     283
58   2010-12      Scandinavian Air     309
59   2010-12    Singapore Airlines     280
60   2011-12            Air Canada     293
61   2011-12           Air Force 1     304
62   2011-12          American Air     279
63   2011-12  American Pan Pacific     330
64   2011-12              Emirates     279
65   2011-12             Japan Air     287
66   2011-12                   KLM     286
67   2011-12             Lufthansa     281
68   2011-12      Scandinavian Air     299
69   2011-12    Singapore Airlines     292
70   2012-12            Air Canada     312
71   2012-12           Air Force 1     291
72   2012-12          American Air     276
73   2012-12  American Pan Pacific     312
74   2012-12              Emirates     303
75   2012-12             Japan Air     304
76   2012-12                   KLM     271
77   2012-12             Lufthansa     282
78   2012-12      Scandinavian Air     301
79   2012-12    Singapore Airlines     286
80   2013-12            Air Canada     274
81   2013-12           Air Force 1     301
82   2013-12          American Air     298
83   2013-12  American Pan Pacific     283
84   2013-12              Emirates     347
85   2013-12             Japan Air     303
86   2013-12                   KLM     270
87   2013-12             Lufthansa     290
88   2013-12      Scandinavian Air     279
89   2013-12    Singapore Airlines     284
90   2014-12            Air Canada     288
91   2014-12           Air Force 1     317
92   2014-12          American Air     312
93   2014-12  American Pan Pacific     296
94   2014-12              Emirates     309
95   2014-12             Japan Air     275
96   2014-12                   KLM     273
97   2014-12             Lufthansa     278
98   2014-12      Scandinavian Air     296
99   2014-12    Singapore Airlines     286
100  2015-12            Air Canada     257
101  2015-12           Air Force 1     291
102  2015-12          American Air     305
103  2015-12  American Pan Pacific     279
104  2015-12              Emirates     331
105  2015-12             Japan Air     285
106  2015-12                   KLM     320
107  2015-12             Lufthansa     306
108  2015-12      Scandinavian Air     280
109  2015-12    Singapore Airlines     276
110  2016-12            Air Canada     274
111  2016-12           Air Force 1     292
112  2016-12          American Air     272
113  2016-12  American Pan Pacific     322
114  2016-12              Emirates     309
115  2016-12             Japan Air     281
116  2016-12                   KLM     263
117  2016-12             Lufthansa     305
118  2016-12      Scandinavian Air     328
119  2016-12    Singapore Airlines     292
120  2017-12            Air Canada     291
121  2017-12           Air Force 1     263
122  2017-12          American Air     298
123  2017-12  American Pan Pacific     312
124  2017-12              Emirates     280
125  2017-12             Japan Air     309
126  2017-12                   KLM     312
127  2017-12             Lufthansa     293
128  2017-12      Scandinavian Air     298
129  2017-12    Singapore Airlines     274
130  2018-12            Air Canada     292
131  2018-12           Air Force 1     261
132  2018-12          American Air     318
133  2018-12  American Pan Pacific     297
134  2018-12              Emirates     312
135  2018-12             Japan Air     297
136  2018-12                   KLM     264
137  2018-12             Lufthansa     286
138  2018-12      Scandinavian Air     300
139  2018-12    Singapore Airlines     303
140  2019-12            Air Canada     272
141  2019-12           Air Force 1     306
142  2019-12          American Air     288
143  2019-12  American Pan Pacific     287
144  2019-12              Emirates     281
145  2019-12             Japan Air     310
146  2019-12                   KLM     288
147  2019-12             Lufthansa     296
148  2019-12      Scandinavian Air     335
149  2019-12    Singapore Airlines     267
150  2020-12            Air Canada     295
151  2020-12           Air Force 1     306
152  2020-12          American Air     267
153  2020-12  American Pan Pacific     305
154  2020-12              Emirates     294
155  2020-12             Japan Air     251
156  2020-12                   KLM     326
157  2020-12             Lufthansa     336
158  2020-12      Scandinavian Air     282
159  2020-12    Singapore Airlines     275
160  2021-12            Air Canada     124
161  2021-12           Air Force 1     132
162  2021-12          American Air     118
163  2021-12  American Pan Pacific     115
164  2021-12              Emirates     134
165  2021-12             Japan Air     110
166  2021-12                   KLM     115
167  2021-12             Lufthansa     125
168  2021-12      Scandinavian Air     130
169  2021-12    Singapore Airlines     110
```

#### `dfp`

```py
Operating_Airlines  Air Canada  Air Force 1  American Air  American Pan Pacific  Emirates  Japan Air  KLM  Lufthansa  Scandinavian Air  Singapore Airlines
Dates                                                                                                                                                     
2005-12                    139          147           138                   148       159        136  137        151               166                 156
2006-12                    277          297           299                   286       312        297  312        290               270                 290
2007-12                    301          268           267                   297       298        291  295        290               316                 307
2008-12                    296          279           286                   316       306        290  286        284               281                 314
2009-12                    312          264           329                   276       284        273  313        304               292                 283
2010-12                    300          279           291                   292       284        309  303        283               309                 280
2011-12                    293          304           279                   330       279        287  286        281               299                 292
2012-12                    312          291           276                   312       303        304  271        282               301                 286
2013-12                    274          301           298                   283       347        303  270        290               279                 284
2014-12                    288          317           312                   296       309        275  273        278               296                 286
2015-12                    257          291           305                   279       331        285  320        306               280                 276
2016-12                    274          292           272                   322       309        281  263        305               328                 292
2017-12                    291          263           298                   312       280        309  312        293               298                 274
2018-12                    292          261           318                   297       312        297  264        286               300                 303
2019-12                    272          306           288                   287       281        310  288        296               335                 267
2020-12                    295          306           267                   305       294        251  326        336               282                 275
2021-12                    124          132           118                   115       134        110  115        125               130                 110
```